# How to edit data of NSArrayController (or to use something else)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, edit, nsarraycontroller, key-value-coding

i created a nsarraycontroller to display its data on my nstableview. this is working. but how do i modify this data now?

```
[arrayController addObject:[...]]
```

adds an object, how do i get it back?

i tried:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [arrayController mutableArrayValueForKey:@"column1"];]
```

but then i get this error

```
2011-05-29 19:25:50.125 TestApp[1665:903] [<NSArrayController 0x113808500> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key column1.
```

(the objects in my arraycontroller representing the rows in my view are of a class (named FileEntry) consisting of 4 properties and i added these as keys to my nsarraycontroller)

i thought kvc-compilant means every attribute has a getter and setter? (and isnt that what properties do?).

i tested my class if i could use this function:

```
FileEntry *entry = [[FileEntry alloc] initWithUrl:@"test"];  //(this adds the string "test" to the property "fileurl")
NSLog(@"%@\n", [entry valueForKey:@"fileurl"]);

and it returns:
> 2011-05-29 19:31:54.760 TestApp[1718:903] test
```

and it works. so how can my class not be kvc-compilant?

anyway, i also tried to use the tableviews datasource instead but cant get those 2 functions to work. would that be of more use than the nsarraycontroller? is it even possible to modify data of the nsarraycontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need a contend array for the NSArrayController to handle, so you could simply take this array and use the NSMutableArray methods. For example you have in your MyController.h a declaration of an array with its setter and getter methods, and you only have to bind the contend array of the array controller to it. Then you can take two buttons for the add and remove methods of the array controller to add something. Now you must bind the value of the column to e.g. FileEntry.fileurl of your array controller managed objects, Now you should be able to add stuff to the table view. And you can also Edit the names in the table view. If you want to get some stuff out of the array in your program somewhere, you can use an outlet of your table view like this:

```
NSInteger row = [myTableViewOutlet selectedRow];
FileEntry* myEntry = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: cool thanks, now it works! i bound my arraycontroller to an array in my appdelegate (i did that before, but i think my error was to init it wrong) and can now add rows to my tableview by adding them to the arraycontroller. i find it a bit weird, adding to arraycontroller, editing in array...